Confused by passing `&mut T` to function as argument
I'm using Rust and sqlx v0.7 to query data from MySQL database. Here is my code:
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), sqlx::Error>{
    let url = "my_connection_string";

    let mut conn = MySqlConnection::connect(url).await?;

    let db = &mut conn;

    sqlx::query!("select full_name from t_author where author_id = '100'").fetch_optional(db).await?;
    sqlx::query!("select full_name from t_author where author_id = '100'").fetch_optional(db).await?;

    println!("sql executed");

    Ok(())
}

Here db is a mutable ref to MySqlConnection. Rust analyzer shows me the following error message:
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `db`
  --> src/main.rs:14:91
   |
11 |     let db = &mut conn;
   |         -- move occurs because `db` has type `&mut MySqlConnection`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
12 |
13 |     sqlx::query!("select full_name from t_author where author_id = '100'").fetch_optional(db).await?;
   |                                                                                           -- value moved here
14 |     sqlx::query!("select full_name from t_author where author_id = '100'").fetch_optional(db).await?;
   |                                                                                           ^^ value used here after move

In this example code, I know I can create a refresh reborrow to db to make codes compiled: sqlx::query!("select full_name from t_author where author_id = '100'").fetch_optional(&mut *db).await?.
But when I wrap the query into a small function, I can do query more than once without creating refresh reborrow, everything goes fine. Here is the code:
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), sqlx::Error>{
    let url = "my_connection_string";

    let mut conn = MySqlConnection::connect(url).await?;

    let db = &mut conn;

    use_arg(db).await?;
    use_arg(db).await?;

    println!("sql executed");

    Ok(())
}

async fn use_arg(db: &mut MySqlConnection) -> Result<(), sqlx::Error> {
    let _ = sqlx::query!("select full_name from t_author where author_id = '100'").fetch_optional(db).await?;
    Ok(())
}

I'm so confused:

If I create refresh reborrow from db, it seems there are 2 mutable ref to original value conn, rust does NOT allow more than one mutable ref at the same time. So what is the relationship between the refresh reborrow and the original mutable ref?
The two versions of my codes look alike, why the new version can be compiled successfully but the old version can not?
I asked AI, AI told me this is about asynchronous context, but the two versions are both async, I don't think this is about async
I read the sqlx document, fetch_optional takes ownership of Executor which &mut MySqlConnection implements
Rust borrow checker says "use of moved value: db", I think the move concept in Rust is about  value rather than mutable ref, is that right?

Any help will be appreciated
I'd like to know what the differences between the two versions codes
